# how to load file from share point online to Azure Blob using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-factory

Can any one help me how to load csv file from share point online to azure Blob storage using Azure Data Factory.

I  tried with Logic apps and succeed however logic app will not upload all file unless  we made any change to the file or upload new.

I need to load all the file even there is no changes.

Answer (score 1):

ADF v2 now supports loading from sharepoint online by OData connector with AAD service principal authentication: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-odata

Comment: Yes, but using Odata url with OData linked service in ADF.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can use a Logic App by changing to a Recurrence Trigger.

On that interval, you List the files in the Library then take any action on them you want.

Comment: Hi Johns-305, my problem is I need to copy all the csv files regardless any update or new file created. but when I setup Logic App I need to choose an option where it says modified or created. As an example I have 3 files A, B and C. I need to copy and move all file each iteration although there is no changes any one of them. But Logic app do not give any option to copy all the file regardless any changes. Can I use Azure Data Factory? But I could not found any example how to connect ADF to Sharepoint Online

Comment: @Sumon changing to a Recurrence Trigger...List the files...take any action (such as copying)

Comment: here is my sample code, Could you please help me where I need to do the change    
 
 
 "triggers": {
            "When_a_file_is_created_or_modified_in_a_folder": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sharepointonline']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",

Comment: "path": "/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('https://sharepoint.com/'))}/triggers/onupdatedfile",
                    "queries": {
                        "folderId": "%252fShared%2bDocuments%252flogicapp",
                        "includeFileContent": true,
                        "inferContentType": true,
                        "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                    }
                },

Comment: "metadata": {
                    "%252fShared%2bDocuments%252flogicapp": "/Shared Documents/logicapp"
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        }

Comment: @Sumon Please read the Answer more carefully.  You would use a Recurrent Trigger.